# How to return object from db but still needing to render errors, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Micropost model and a Gallery model and a Picture model and the pictures either belong to Micropost or Gallery model. I have a micropost form where it `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures` and have set the associations in models, and, controller micropost create action and strong parameters look like this,

Micropost_controller

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.create(micropost_params)
  @pictures = @micropost.pictures
  @pictures.each do |pic|
    pic.update!(gallery_id: params[:gallery_id])
  end   
  ...
  render 'static_pages/home'
end

def micropost_params
  params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, pictures_attributes: [:id, :gal_refs_id, :picture, :_destroy]))
end
```

The gallery is preset so I have its id which is sent in a hidden field and retrieved in the microposts controller as shown.

Problem is I need to return the `@micropost` object so I can update the `:gallery_id`, so I cannot use `@micropost.save` as it only returns `true` or `false` and this is the behavior I need to re-render the form if errors occur.

At the moment using create it silently fails and renders the template.

How can I overcome this or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code. If @micropost has no errors, it will create @micropost and you can update its associated objects

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save
    # if the object has no errors
    @pictures = @micropost.pictures
    @pictures.each do |pic|
      pic.update!(gallery_id: params[:gallery_id])
    end   
    ...
    render 'static_pages/home'
  else
    # show Errors
    @micropost.errors
  end
end

def micropost_params
  params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, pictures_attributes: [:id, :gal_refs_id, :picture, :_destroy]))
end
```

Comment: Hey, I thought it did not return the @micropost object guess I should have tried and seen. I must have missunderstood what returning the object meant?

Comment: Although this will 'work', if there's an error while updating the pictures, the User will not know and it will fail silently in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Models:

```
class Micropost
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, inverse_of: :imageable
end

class Picture
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Gallery
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, inverse_of: :imageable
end

# Note: inverse_of is important here! It allows you to instantiate the
#       Picture object without having a Picture object yet.
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = micropost.new(micropost_params)

  @pictures.each do |picture|
    @micropost.pictures.new({
      picture: picture,
      gallery_id: params[:gallery_id]
    })
  end

  # Note: Pictures will not be saved or persisted in the database until
  #       .save is called.
  # Note: If your Picture object is invalid, Micropost save will also fail

  if @micropost.save
    # Saved, do something here with the success response
    render 'static_pages/home'
  else
    # Errors
    @micropost.errors
  end
end
```

Picture Validation:
This is code from my production app, adjust to your needs.

```
    steam_game_details['images'].each do |image|
      image_file_name = image.split('/').last.split('?').first

      local_picture = picture.where({
        picture_file_name: image_file_name
      }).first_or_initialize

      # Check if the image is nil and whether or not it actually exists on AWS S3
      # 
      if local_picture.picture.nil? || !local_picture.picture.exists?
        local_picture.assign_attributes({
          picture: open(URI.parse(image)),
          picture_file_name: image_file_name # Overwrite the name generated by Paperclip
        })
      end
    end
```

Comment: What is `@pictures` here? did you leave out `@pictures = @micropost.pictures` ?

Comment: Yep, sorry. `@pictures`, based on your code, is `@pictures = @micropost.pictures` .

Comment: Yes I never thought of that, I can call save on the @pictures as it has @micropost variable in it. This will not duplicate saving the picture when calling save? Ie on both `(micropost_params)` and the @pictures block?

Comment: It will duplicate if you don't check whether or not the picture exists. I've updated the code with a 'validation' of sorts of what I currently use in my apps with Paperclip.

Comment: Ok I see what your doing, I may implement this if I decide to go with this!